# Unable to restore SQL Server 2008 R2 Express backup file onto SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a `.bak` file which I created using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express .

I tried to restore it to a SQL Server 2012 Express but got the following error messages:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RealEstate.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   File 'RealEstate' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RealEstate.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RealEstate_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   File 'RealEstate_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RealEstate_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Can somebody please help me solve this problem?

For your information,

the `.bak` file was created from the SQL Server 2008 R2 database running on my old PC which died last month.

I just bought a new PC and decided to install SQL Server 2012 instead.

I would like to restore this `.bak` file into the SQL Server 2012 running on my new PC.

In SQL Server 2008 R2, the databases are stored in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA.
```

Meanwhile in SQL Server 2012, the databases are stored in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA.
```

I wonder if the original path is indeed stored in the `.bak` file. Does anybody know about this?

Comment: Please!! format you question and make it readable.

Comment: **Yes - of course** it's the path! **READ** the error message (*The system cannot find the path specified*) - it clearly tells you that it's trying to store the files from the backup to the old (2008 R2) path which doesn't exist on your new machine anymore! You will need to restore the backup file and **explicitly specify** where the files should go (to your **new** directory)

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving from SQL 2008 to SQL 2012 try something like this.

```
RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM DISK = 'C:\Path\To\Bak\File' WITH REPLACE;
```

Comment: Did you create a blank database on the 2012 server with the same name before hand?

Answer (score 0):

```
RESTORE DATABASE RealRestate
   FROM DISK = 'C:\PATH_TO\RealEstate.bak'
   WITH MOVE '<dataname>' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RealEstate.mdf',
        MOVE '<logname>' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\RealEstate_log.ldf', REPLACE
```

Notice, I already put in the new location

the `<dataname>` and `<logname>` can be found with

```
restore filelistonly from disk ='C:\PATH_TO\RealEstate.bak'
```

This will restore nothing, but show you the properties of you bak file. In the column `Logicalname`, you will see the names for `<dataname>` (where the type is D)  and `<logname>` (where the Type is L)